# is there a tomee-maven-plugin version that support Java 14?

Tags: java, maven, apache-tomee

I am using tomee-maven-plugin version 8.0.5 (The latest found on mvn repository) to generate an executable Jar of my JSF Project,

```
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.tomee.maven</groupId>
<artifactId> </artifactId>
<version>8.0.5</version>
 <executions>
   <execution>
     <id>executable-jar</id>
      <goals>
           <goal>exec</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>package</phase>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

The package command works fine and I got the War and Jar
but when I launch the Server

```
java -jar MyJar.jar
```

I am using Java 14 The deploiement on Tomee is working fine in Eclipse
, The app loading causes this error :

```
        Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to create annotation scanner for web module MonProjet-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Unable to read class definition for gestion.controller.GuestServiceControler
            at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.addWebModule(DeploymentLoader.java:886)
            at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.load(DeploymentLoader.java:233)
            at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.loadApplication(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:2361)
            ... 44 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to read class definition for gestion.controller.GuestServiceControler
            at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.readClassDef(AnnotationFinder.java:1180)
            at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.<init>(AnnotationFinder.java:153)
            at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.<init>(AnnotationFinder.java:166)
            at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory$OpenEJBAnnotationFinder.<init>(FinderFactory.java:546)
            at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.newFinder(FinderFactory.java:267)
            at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.create(FinderFactory.java:80)
            at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.createFinder(FinderFactory.java:69)
            at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.addWebModule(DeploymentLoader.java:878)
            ... 46 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 58
            at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:195)
            at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:176)
            at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:162)
            at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:283)
            at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.readClassDef(AnnotationFinder.java:1176
```

I did my researchs about this and the problem is in the "org.apache.xbean.asm7" dependency, I was trying to override this dependency by forcing the plugin to use  "org.apache.xbean.asm8" but it didn't work
and there is no other versions of Maven plugin to use
Does anyone have more information about this ?
Thank you

Comment: I have my doubts that you get tomee for JDK 12+ based on that https://tomee.apache.org/tomee-9.0/docs/java-compatibility.html I would say max. JDK11 if it really works...

Comment: @khmarbaise yeah , I tried building it with JDK8 and that worked fine , thank you for this information I didn't know that Tomee is not compatible with JDK14 
What about Tomcat 9 ? iss there a plugin to create an executable JAR with Embedded Tomcat ?

Comment: Java 14 is obsolete. Use Java 15 or Java 11.

Comment: I doubt that Tomee works on JDK 15 cause does not even work on JDK 14..... based on the things documented it looks like only JDK 11 is supported where I'm not 100% sure (I couldn't find a really good release notes informations where things have been fixed. Apart from that JEE 9 is not finished very long? November?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Older **TomEE <= 8.0.6** are still using a shaded version of **asm7**, which has only limited support for newer Java versions (max. JDK 13). This also affects several transiend dependencies of Tomee such as OWB, CXF, etc.

Actually, were was some work related to JDK 16 as well as some open pull requests pending in order to support JDK16 with the next TomEE release:

- https://github.com/apache/tomee/pull/776
- https://github.com/apache/tomee/pull/777
- https://github.com/apache/tomee/commit/51610f832c8d802c7b4e0c3d42552d7f7536fd44

From my experience, **TomEE 8.0.6** runs fine with **JDK11**. So for now, you should go with JDK11 and wait until the next TomEE release with the related changes is out.

**Update (15.04.2021)**

I am currently running a TomEE 8.0.7-SNAPSHOT (Plume) with JDK-16 (it also works with the Maven Plugin).

For now, the following adjustments are necessary:

1. You need to remove OpenJPA 3.1.2 and its transient asm8 dependeny in `<libs>` via `<lib>remove:openjpa</lib>` and `<lib>remove:xbean-asm8-shaded</lib>` and re-add the latest `3.1.3-SNAPSHOT` via `<lib>org.apache.openjpa:openjpa:3.1.3-SNAPSHOT</lib>`
2. For now, it requires to specify `<args>--illegal-access=permit</args>` in the plugin configuration to allow some reflection and other stuff. Java 16 switched the default.

**Update (10.10.2022)**

TomEE 8.0.9 supports **JDK17** out of the box.